# Icons over the web, converted into images

Tags: google-chrome, web

Icons like ☔☕☝♈♉♊♋♌♍♎♏♐♑♒♓♿⚓⚡⚪⚫⚽⚾⛄⛅⛎⛔⛪⛲⛳⛵   ⛹⛺⛽ have been changed into images. You will notice that if you try highlighting them like text: their colors wont invert as text-symbols do.
[I just found these here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols)

This is how I see them with Chrome in the same Wikipedia page
[image: 0]

Is there a list of exactly all the changed ones? I don't even know if there's a technical name for them so that I can investigate more about this change.

Comment: They appear like characters and I am able to highlight them in chrome.

Comment: Unicode.org, perhaps emojis, http://unicode.org/emoji/

Comment: I can highlight them as text in Firefox and IE just fine. Where did you get the ones you included here? If from a web page, did you look at the page source to see how they did it?

Comment: I answered the question to clarify the situation I'm in. Turns out it involves only to Discord and Chrome users at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments here, visualizing from a different browser (Firefox), and asking people (which I know they have Discord installed)

### Turns out there never was a change over the web 
<sup><del>and ashamed myself with the initial question title in the process</del>.</sup>

> This is how it looks from Chrome browser, with Discord installed in Windows.
>   [image]

It's a local replacement provoked by Discord (a standalone Chromium program). For some reason, after installing it, it also changed the way I see many of the unicode icons within Google Chrome.

### Have I checked the extensions?

Yes, and there's no extension installed that has anything to do with this, no Discord-related extension whatsoever. I even disabled every one for the sake of trial and error (I only have Adblock Plus and Stylish, apart from default google docs), but still no difference.

However, if I use any other web browser (i.e. Firefox), I am able to see unicode icons normally.

I don't know the reason behind the scenes, but seems like a Discord feature extended into every Chromium-built program "accidentally".

Comment: On a side note: if you copypaste the same characters in facebook, these would be replaced by coloured images, no matter the web browser you're using.